# App has stopped while trying to display data from database. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, database

I'm currently trying to display a data from my database which I currently created. But when I try to run it in my phone, it always stops. This is my code

Edit Users Screen.java

```
    TextView textView;
    String text = " ";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_users);

        // added

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        // inserting users
        db.addUsers(new Users("1", "Julian", "juliankurtseguiran@gmail.com",      "seguiran"));

        // reading and displaying all users (you can remove it on where it should be placed

        List<Users> users = db.getAllUsers();

        for (Users u : users) 
        {
            String log = "ID number:" + u.getIDnumber() + "Name:" + u.getName() +
                    "Email:" + u.getEmail() + "Password:" + u.getPassword();

            text = text + log;
        }

        textView.setText(text);
    }
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_USERS + "("
                + KEY_IDNUMBER + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + "TEXT,"
                +  KEY_EMAIL + "TEXT," + KEY_PASSWORD + "TEXT," + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_USERS);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    void addUsers (Users users) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values  =  new ContentValues();
        values.put("KEY_NAME", users.getName());
        values.put("KEY_EMAIL", users.getEmail());
        values.put("KEY_PASSWORD", users.getPassword());

        db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
        db.close();

    }

    Users getUsers (int idnumber) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS, new String[] {KEY_IDNUMBER, KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_PASSWORD}, KEY_IDNUMBER
         + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(idnumber)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null ){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        Users users = new Users (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),       cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));

        return users;


    }

    public List<Users> getAllUsers(){
        List<Users> usersList = new ArrayList<>();

        String selectQuery ="SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USERS;

        SQLiteDatabase db  = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Users users = new Users();
                users.setIDnumber(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                users.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                users.setEmail(cursor.getString(2));
                users.setPassword(cursor.getString(3));

                usersList.add(users);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return usersList;
    }

    public int updateUsers (Users users) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("KEY_NAME", users.getName());
        values.put("KEY_EMAIL", users.getEmail());
        values.put("KEY_PASSWORD", users.getPassword());

        return db.update(TABLE_USERS, values, KEY_IDNUMBER + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(users.getIDnumber())});

    }

    public void deleteUsers (Users users) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_USERS, KEY_IDNUMBER + "=?",
        new String[]{String.valueOf(users.getIDnumber())});

        db.close();
    }

    public int getUsersCount() {

        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USERS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        return cursor.getCount();
    }
```

Users.java

```
    public class Users 
    {
        int IDnumber;
        String Name;
        String Email;
        String Password;

        public Users(int i, String string, String cursorString, String s) {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Email = Email;
            this.Password = Password;
        }

        public Users() {

        }

        public Users(String s, String julian, String cursorString, String seguiran) {
        }

        public int getIDnumber() {
            return IDnumber;
        }

        public void setIDnumber(int IDnumber) {
            this.IDnumber = IDnumber;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return Name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            Name = name;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return Email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            Email = email;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return Password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            Password = password;
        }
    }
```

Logcat

```
4-03 12:14:14.591 2418-2418/com.example.aadre.saferhomeph V/FA: onActivityCreated
04-03 12:14:14.651 2418-2418/com.example.aadre.saferhomeph E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "TABLEusers": syntax error
04-03 12:14:14.651 2418-2418/com.example.aadre.saferhomeph D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-03 12:14:14.651 2418-2418/com.example.aadre.saferhomeph W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d85c08)
04-03 12:14:14.671 2418-2418/com.example.aadre.saferhomeph E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.aadre.saferhomeph, PID: 2418
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aadre.saferhomeph/com.example.aadre.saferhomeph.Edit_Users_Screen}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEusers": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEusers(idnumber INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nameTEXT, email TEXT, password TEXT )
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                              Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEusers": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEusers(idnumber INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nameTEXT, email TEXT, password TEXT )
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:690)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1806)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1737)
                                                                                 at com.example.aadre.saferhomeph.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:38)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
                                                                                 at com.example.aadre.saferhomeph.DatabaseHelper.addUsers(DatabaseHelper.java:50)
                                                                                 at com.example.aadre.saferhomeph.Edit_Users_Screen.onCreate(Edit_Users_Screen.java:33)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5322)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
04-03 12:14:14.791 2418-2430/com.example.aadre.saferhomeph V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=2, ext1=0, ext2=0
04-03 12:14:14.791 2418-2430/com.example.aadre.saferhomeph V/MediaPlayer: playback complete
04-03 12:14:14.791 2418-2430/com.example.aadre.saferhomeph V/MediaPlayer: callback application
04-03 12:14:14.791 2418-2430/com.example.aadre.saferhomeph V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
04-03 12:14:14.791 2418-2430/com.example.aadre.saferhomeph V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=7, ext1=0, ext2=0
04-03 12:14:14.791 2418-2430/com.example.aadre.saferhomeph V/MediaPlayer: unrecognized message: (7, 0, 0)
04-03 12:14:14.791 2418-2430/com.example.aadre.saferhomeph V/MediaPlayer: callback application
04-03 12:14:14.791 2418-2430/com.example.aadre.saferhomeph V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
04-03 12:14:19.561 2418-2456/com.example.aadre.saferhomeph W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

pls help

Comment: [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/5221149)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0):

Remove "," after `TEXT` from `create table`

```
String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "("
        + KEY_IDNUMBER + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
        +  KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";

db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS_TABLE);
```

Comment: still app has stop and closes :(

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: Edited. Added Logcat

Comment: give space after TABLE .. check given code.."CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS

Comment: change CREATE_USERS_TABLE and post your logcat and your new code of datbase helper class

Answer (score 0):

write create query this way 
String CREATE_USERS_TABLE ="create table  if not exists contactmaster(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,name varchar(50),mob number(10))";

Comment: It automatically closes right after I click the button. :(